# AngularJS: Add class to element when all items in list have the same value

Tags: angularjs

I have this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j3ca/3kpoL6vg/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'active': item.active}" ng-click="item.active = !item.active">{{ item.name }}</div>
<button ng-click="mark()" ng-class="{'marked': allMarked}">Mark all</button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function MainCtrl($scope){
$scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1', active: false },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2', active: false },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3', active: false },
    { id: 4, name: 'Item 4', active: false }
];

$scope.allMarked = false;
$scope.mark = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if($scope.allMarked) {
            $scope.items[i].active = false;
        } else {
            $scope.items[i].active = true;
        }
    }
    $scope.allMarked = !$scope.allMarked;

}
```

}

I have the following functionalities:

- click on a list item changes "active" property of an item and sets its background to green if active == true;
- click on Mark all button sets all list elements to "active" and
  changes color of the button;

What I would like to do is this:

- If I manually select all items in the list the button also changes
  color to green;
- If I click on Mark all button, but then I uncheck one item manually, the button should change its color back to red (since not all items are selected);

What I need is this basically: http://plnkr.co/edit/N98IKTcHoZMCs18FjSRF?p=preview 
But not with checkboxes, I need divs.

My idea is: every time i click on a link, I check (`for` loop) if all other items are active, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary looping :)
Is there a way in angular to determine (on click) if all items in a list have the same value of a certain property?
I am new to Angular, help would be much appreciated :)

**Updated fiddle**

I've updated my fiddle link, but that is clearly a terrible terrible solution :) Any ideas? Is there a way to check item's active value without looping on every click?

Comment: Implement the solution that you have in mind. Make it work. Then see if it causes a performance problem. If and only if it does, then start thinking about optimizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to check that all of the items are marked or not. Changing `allMarked` to something similar to this:

```
$scope.allMarked = function () {
    return $scope.items.every(function (item) {
        return item.active;
    });
};
```

An example can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3kpoL6vg/2/).

Comment: THAT is just a beautiful piece of code, just what I needed. I don't know if it is faster (but I don't think it will show on so little data), but it is definitely neat :) Thank you!

Comment: @j3ca There will be some performance issues when your list grows huge, but even then the slow down is usually due to rendering/manipulating the DOM and not the iteration on the array.